# How to get most used pixel color from an image in Xamarin.Forms for iOS?

Tags: xaml, image-processing, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

**What I'm trying to do**

- I'm trying to download an image from any given URL and find the most used pixelcolor from this image and save it as a HTML color code (string) like this: "#33AAFF".

**This is what I have so far:**

- I download images from a URL using WebClient and save it as a byte array:

  `byte[] data = new WebClient().DownloadData(x.Url)`
- I'm able to convert this byte array to a Xamarin.Forms.ImageSource using this code (to display it in my Xaml view):

  `var imageSource = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(data));`

**I've been trying to convert to a System.Drawing.Bitmap, but got some Memory issues. If I had it as Bitmap, then this code would probably solve my issue:**

```
public static string GetDominantColor(this Bitmap bmp)
    {
        //Used for tally
        int r = 0;
        int g = 0;
        int b = 0;

        int total = 0;

        for (int x = 0; x < bmp.Width; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < bmp.Height; y++)
            {
                Color clr = bmp.GetPixel(x, y);

                r += clr.R;
                g += clr.G;
                b += clr.B;

                total++;
            }
        }

        //Calculate average
        r /= total;
        g /= total;
        b /= total;

        return ColorTranslator.ToHtml(Color.FromArgb(r, g, b));
    }
```

The algorithm for calculating these values looks easy to implement, however I don't have much experience in developing apps in Xamarin and can't find a way to loop through all the pixels and get their color codes.

Can someone help me out here?

**UPDATE:**
This code seems to work when running from an iPhone 8 iPhoneSimulator, but crashes when connecting to my local device (my own iphone XR):

```
var downloadedBytes = new WebClient().DownloadData(cat.Url);
var htmlColorCode = SKBitmap.Decode(downloadedBytes)?.GetDominantColor();
```

Where this is the method for GetDominantColor():

```
public static string GetDominantColor(this SKBitmap bmp)
    {
        //Used for tally
        int r = 0;
        int g = 0;
        int b = 0;

        int total = 0;

        for (int x = 0; x < bmp.Width; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < bmp.Height; y++)
            {
                SKColor clr = bmp.GetPixel(x, y);

                r += clr.Red;
                g += clr.Green;
                b += clr.Blue;

                total++;
            }
        }

        //Calculate average
        r /= total;
        g /= total;
        b /= total;

        return $"#{r:X2}{g:X2}{b:X2}";
    }
```

Comment: converting to an ImageSource won't help you with doing any analysis.  You also can't use System.Drawing - look into SkiaSharp instead.  You probably would need to convert into a Skia bitmap and simply traverse it and check every pixel, unless there is some sort of colormap in Skia you can use

Comment: what line causes the crash?

Comment: @Jason Last time I checked it crashed in this method: `SKBitmap.Decode(downloadedBytes)`, but right now the debugger in vsstudio won't stop at any of my breakpoints.. I guess I have to fix that first. Thanks for helping me. I'll keep you updated :)

Comment: have you tried catching the exception?

Comment: Ok, so what is the exception causing the crash?

Comment: @Jason Finally fixed the debugger problem. I can confirm that it crashes on this line: `SKBitmap.Decode(downloadedBytes)`, tried using try-catch, but the Exception was null. But when the app has crashed, I get to see this message for a couple of seconds: `System.TypeInitializationException: 'The type initializer for 'SkiaSharp.SKAbstractManagedStream' threw an exception.'`. I have the SkiaSharp by Microsoft nuget package installed

Comment: @Jason Any idea what I can do to fix this? Everything works fine for the iphone simulator.

Comment: Have you checked that the downloaded bytes are not null and are valid image data?

Comment: @Jason Yes, if I remove the SKBitmap.Decode() line that causes the crash, the bytes are turned into an ImageSource object and displayed correctly

Comment: No idea.  There are a couple of similar but unresolved errors logged in github.  You might try playing with the Linker settings, or compare them between the sim and device builds.  Or try a different version of Skia

Comment: @Jason
`{System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'SkiaSharp.SKData' threw an exception. ---> System.DllNotFoundException: @rpath/libSkiaSharp.framework/libSkiaSharp assembly:<unknown assembly> type:<unknown type> member:(null)
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) SkiaSharp.SkiaApi.sk_data_new_empty()
  at SkiaSharp.SKData..cctor `

Comment: Does this tell you anything? Both projects have these nuget packages installed: `SkiaSharp v2.80.0, SkiaSharp.Extended v1.6, SkiaSharp.NativeAssets.Linux.NoDependencies v2.80.0`

Tried with different versions, tried to change the Linker settings, compared the builds. Still the same exception that I mentioned above, on this line: `SKBitmap.Decode(downloadedBytes)`

Comment: You can create a new issue in Github : https://github.com/mono/SkiaSharp/issues